# Как открыть ссылку из приложения на android не в WebView, а в броузере Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview

```
        <a class="menu-item" href="#" style="background-color:#007dff;color:white;" onclick="newDocC();"><img class="img25" src="images/cellm.png"/>&nbsp;<u>CellMapper.net</u></a>
            <script>
            function newDocC() {
            window.location.assign("https://www.cellmapper.net/map?MCC="+MC+" &MNC="+MN+"&type=LTE&latitude=52.83074868584791&longitude=38.272402246227635&zoom=5");
            }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
     @Override
     public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
          String scheme = Uri.parse(url).getScheme();
          if (scheme.equals("http") & scheme.equals("https")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Выберите приложение"));
                return true;
          }
          return false;
     }
});
```

Comment: А куда в моем примере вставить это?

Comment: У Вас задача - открывать ссылки из WebView в браузере Chrome?

Comment: Да, открывать эту ссылку из WebView в браузере Chrome.

Comment: Вам нужно переопределить функцию shouldOverrideUrlLoading. Изменил ответ.

Comment: Где мне это прописать ? Я еще учусь этим вещам.

Comment: mWebView в моем ответе - это Ваше webView. Перед передачей в него ссылки вызывайте этот код.